# Rails dissabling user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm working on project were users can log in and users can be disabled, user states are changed via [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) and user managing is realized using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). My problem is that users can disable themselves. I should add a condition to the state change something like:

```
transition :enabled => :disabled, :disabled => :enabled, if: :not_self_disabling
```

`not_self_disabling` is a method in the User class; the only problem is that `current_user` is not known in model, and also accessing session is ugly, as it violates MVC's separation of concerns. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do users disable themselves? Please show us the controller and model code that handles that interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to tell whether this really is the best way to set up user disabling. It may just be better to protect against self-disabling in the controller. However, you can do something like (untested):

```
event :toggle_user_status do
  transition :enabled => :disabled, :disabled => :enabled
end

def toggle_user_status(current_user, *args)
  super unless current_user == self
  # Note: it may be necessary (or better) to do `super(*args)`, 
  # since state_machine doesn't need to know about your `current_user`
end
```

And then pass in your `current_user` to the `toggle_user_status` method. Overriding `event` methods is described in the RDoc here: [http://rubydoc.info/github/pluginaweek/state_machine/StateMachine/Machine:event](http://rubydoc.info/github/pluginaweek/state_machine/StateMachine/Machine%3aevent).